# Can I use hector_slam only with Sick TIM551

Tags: ros, hector-slam, 2d-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I will use only a laser scanner from SICK TIM551 to build a map. Like this. Maybe lead by hand.
[image description http://answers.ros.org/upfiles/13535404469074751.png](http://answers.ros.org/upfiles/13535404469074751.png)

I choose the hector slam.

Would that work??

thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211200/can-i-use-hector_slam-only-with-sick-tim551/) by [Kartierung_ss15](https://answers.ros.org/users/22751/kartierung_ss15/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-06-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, for hector slam laser with high frequency rate is enough. Odomerty is optional.

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2015-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0